# Webpack 5 with old Angular versions for Module Federation

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I have 10+ apps that are running on various Angular versions and I have a shell app that binds them together using a custom runtime and build process. Now, with Webpack 5 I am trying to use Module Federation. However, I have some apps that are on Angular 8 which I don't want to upgrade right away. If I try to force Webpack 5 on top of Angular 8, I see that devkit methods of 8 are deprecated with Webpack 5.

Is there any way we can still use Webpack 5 with older versions of Angular?

Comment: I think webpack5 can only be used from v11 (opt-in using yarn only). It’s an interesting question I myself wondered about.

Comment: @MikeOne thanks for your reply. So that leaves us with only one option - to bring the apps to Angular 12 first, isn't it?

Comment: I’m seriously not sure. I suspect, maybe with build-plus or something similar, you could maybe inject the plugin settings for webpack and potentially still be able to use the federation plugin? I could also imagine you could maybe convert to a webcomponent and then set that up as remote..?

Comment: yup, webcomponent is going to be my plan-b; it's working just fine but I am trying to have one consistent approach :) Let me try exploring more on the build-plus option you mentioned.. thanks mate.

Comment: Good luck! I’d love to hear what you come up with. Also, the MFE specialist is on Twitter and pretty responsive to questions.

Comment: Good afternoon, did you find a solution to use the Module Federation with angular 8?

Comment: @henrique_ms sadly, no. I decided to go with "web-components" based MFEs with a generic event-bus-architecture.

Comment: @vp310 Do you have any githubrepo or some code samples which uses angular 8 code as webcomponent?

Comment: @VikasKrishnan you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/elements/v/8.0.0 to create your Angular 8 components as web-components.